# How to I put a dynamic php page into the jquery accordian "active" section

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am redoing my site and have at any time 80-120 vehicles, all identified in my db by their unique stock number. I'm using jQuery's accordion to list the vehicles: 
http://www.login.carcityofdanbury.com/New/?cat=01

How do I embed `edit.php?stock=__STOCK__` into the div of the open accordion, once the accordion opens?
I tried just using just an HTML `<embed>` tag, but it is making the page load extremely slow.

I am new to the whole jQuery, Ajax, coding thing and am completely a self taught "learn as I go" guy, so a demo, tutorial or example would be great.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Helps in tailoring an answer better.

Comment: You could get help here:
`http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of jQuery .load function (http://api.jquery.com/load/) and the jQuery UI Accordion change event (http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#event-change) which gets triggered after an accordion slide opens:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#listVehicles").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        change: function(event, ui){
            ui.newContent.load('edit.php', { stock: __STOCK__ });
        }
    });

});​
```

When the change event is triggered, the edit.php file is loaded using AJAX and the HTML is dropped into the opened accordion slide.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to accomplish... Thank you Scrooby

Comment: Actually its not passing the $stock variable onto the edit.php page

Comment: You might need to pass your $stock value through the data parameter of the jQuery load function. I've amended my answer to pass it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could get some help here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Example:

```
$.ajax({
       url: "yourPage.php",
       success: function(data){
         $("#youarea").text(data);
       }
     });
```

Comment: Where would this code go, and how do I know what the "#yourarea" is? The div's don't have an id that I assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the jQuery [`load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which is designed for this specifically. You give it an element, and a url and it will load the content into the element.

So, in your Accordion handling code, you'll want to place the following:

```
$('#elementToLoadInto').load('edit.php?stock='+id');
```

From there, your PHP page should server up a single (or multiple if needed) `<div>` element, not a full HTML page. That content will be placed into `#elementToLoadInto` exactly as it is, just like it was coded there.

jQuery can also [load only a piece of the page](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments), so you could also take advantage of that functionality if you need to return a full HTML page for some other reasons.